# Jumping into memcached - know any good guides?

Tags: memcached

I'm looking to get into storing data in memcached and enhance a few areas of my site.  I've googled around for guides in PHP and am finding limited or very old articles.  There's always the documentation but I'd prefer to read from someone who's experienced to ensure proper setup.

**update**

Specific topics I'd like to get details on / questions answered...

- How often does it refresh the cache?
- For your average site that has member accounts to be logged in on all pages, is it generally a good idea to store sessions in memcache?
- Does the length of the keys of values have any noticable effect on performance for getting/setting the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one out ... they may be old but I doubt much has changed.

[Using Memcache with MySQL and PHP](http://pureform.wordpress.com/2008/05/21/using-memcache-with-mysql-and-php/)